# Console Application is not running and shows nothing

Tags: c++, console

The problem is to solve this.

*The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?*

I wrote this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool prime(long int a);

int main()
{
long int b = 600851475143/2;
long int k;



for(long int i = 1; i <= b ; i++)
{
    if(b % i == 0 && prime(i) == true)
        {
            k = i;
        }
}
cout << k << endl;
return 0;



}

bool prime(long int a) 
{
bool p = true; 

for(long int i = 2; i <= sqrt(a) && p == true ; i++) 
     if(a % i == 0) p = false;

return p;
}
```

and when I execute after a build, it opens a console , and shows nothing

Comment: Debuggers are a brilliant tool for solving problems like this. Pop a breakpoint at the start of the program, start up the program, and start start stepping until the program blocks or starts going around in circles.

Comment: g++ spits out *warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
 long int b = 600851475143/2;* You should resolve this. Come to think of it, 600851475143/2; is a darn big number. You might want to reconsider using it as a loop bound.

Comment: Regarding the `prime` computation, this is a brutally slow way to do this. Consider the number of times you are recomputing the `i = 2` case.

Comment: I didn't complete the previous thought. Use memoization to reduce the amount of redundant work you have to do. See if you can take advantage of a Prime Number Sieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add a cout statement inside the for loop in main. Your program is running, it's just taking a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. 600851475143/2 is just a large number, so you have to wait some minutes till the result will be printed.
Further you're testing kind of twice if it a prime which makes the complexity unnecessarily much higher. 
Try this:

```
long int b = 600851475143/2;
long int k = b;
for(long int i = 2; i < b ; i++)
{
    if(b % i == 0)
    {
        k = i;
        break;
    }
}
cout << k << endl;
```

Comment: I think the problem is given for this. Maybe there is more optimal way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @ManeHambardzumyan Look into cryptography. Factoring huge numbers into primes is something they do every day and they have a lot of tricks to make it easier to compute.